# Updating field in feature class using ArcPy cursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I want to update a field in my feature class. I tried to use a da.SearchCursor (code below) but was quickly reminded that tuples are immutable... I ran the code but it failed with a `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`.

How do I most efficiently retrieve all rows from a feature class and update a field of each row and save it back to the feature class?

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fldNames) as sc:
    for thing in sc:
        tmp = 0

        #
        # do stuff here
        #

        thing[idxField] = tmp
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use an [Update Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000), not a Search Cursor. It allows the same retrieve rows and loop through process, but also enables updating fields.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fldNames) as uc:
    for thing in uc:
        # assign the data to the various fields
        thing[0] = tmp0
        thing[1] = tmp1
        # trigger an update (save) for that row
        uc.updateRow(thing)
```

Comment: you'll need `uc.updateRow(thing)` instead of `cursor`

Comment: Ha, yes. I'm so used to my own syntax ;)